# Multi-threaded PUPL SQL Error code 000099997 occurred in module CIPPUPFN:HA100 - UPDATE TCTL

Tags: oracle-ccb

We are on CC&B 2.6. We run base process *PUPL Payment Upload* on 8 threads. Occasionally the process fails on a thread. The other threads run successfully. And when we restart the job, that thread recovers and completes successfully.

The error message shown is:
SQL Error code 000099997 occurred in module CIPPUPFN:HA100 - UPDATE TCTL

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem might have been caused by a bug in the product that handles the interaction of
sessions and the ThreadlocalStorage object. Some session-related state, such
as the map of DBLocalCobolSQLProcessBackend instances was stored on
ThreadlocalStorage, when it should be on FrameworkSession.

If another session is temporarily "pushed" onto ThreadlocalStorage (e.g. via
SessionExecutable>>doInReadOnlySession()) the original session is set aside
but the map of DBLocalCobolSQLProcessBackend was improperly destroyed and could not be restored when the original session was restored.

If a subsequent db-related call from COBOL into Java requires access to an instance of DBLocalCobolSQLProcessBackend, the desired instance was missing and a new, empty one was created, which lead to a NPE in downstream code.